# opposite of digital, but not analogue

Tags: antonyms

I'm currently writing a security guideline for my company, and I need to make different rules for digital files and documents on paper.

I was wondering if there were any good words to mean "on paper".

Analogue is obviously not the word. Non-digital seems alright, but it somewhat give too much emphasis to digital files. It makes it seem as if digital is one thing and there's the rest, and that's not the case.

I would really appreciate it if you could find the word that would fit just right.

Comment: "Hard copy" is the term that I've always heard used.  (And, BTW, despite common use, "analog(ue)" is not the antonym of "digital".)

Comment: @HotLicks - You're not an electrical engineer, are you? Within the field, the two _are_ antonyms, although in certain circumstances one can speak of an analog analysis of a digital circuit, or the analog characteristics of a digital signal. But note that the exceptions imply the distinction nonetheless.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - EE and programmer who actually used analog computers back then they occupied half a room.

Comment: @HotLicks - Yours only took up half a room? You were lucky. OK, seriously, please expand on your objection.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - There was one at Wright-Pat that took up a whole room, but I never got to play with that one.  (No objection, just observing that the terms are poorly understood, to the point that they are acquiring new meanings based on the misunderstandings.)

Comment: @HotLicks - Well, actually I just couldn't resist doing a "Four Welshmen" riff. But seriously, you have not expanded on your original comment. Why is analog not an antonym of digital? And if it isn't, what is?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - "Analog" means "analogous to" and can validly be applied to any computer simulation.  "Digital" means (very roughly) "in discrete digits".  "Analog" (in it's original form, 50 or so years ago) had nothing to do with *how* the data was represented, whether in digits, voltage levels, or hand signals.  "Linear" is a (slightly) more proper antonym for "digital".

Comment: @HotLicks - this link http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241379/what-is-the-origin-of-analogue-as-a-term-meaning-non-digital begs to differ. "Analog" apparently derives from the computational technology, and refers to the controlled function, voltage for instance, which is directly analogous to the process being modeled. Linear or non-linear has nothing to do with analog or non-analog (digital).

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - "Analog(ue)" was a word before computers existed.

Comment: Yes, but "analog(ue) electronics" was not - not a phrase, that is.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest either *[print](http://thefreedictionary.com/print) documents*

> *adj.*
>   Of, relating to, writing for, or constituting printed publications: *a print journalist; print coverage*

or

*[printed](http://thefreedictionary.com/printed) documents*

> *v.tr.*
>
> 3.
>   a. To produce by means of pressed type, an electronic printer, or similar means, on a paper surface.
>
> b. To offer in printed form; publish.

The distinction between these is fairly subtle: I would take 'print documents' to relate to documents printed by any physical method, whereas I would usually assume that 'printed documents' implied some kind of official or semi-official (e.g. company-wide) publication on paper. Essentially, a *printed document* is more important, or is accorded higher status, than some mere *print document*.

Answer (score 7):

You could make a distinction between electronic and non-electronic documents, but one document could of course exist in digital and paper form...

If you are mainly dealing with electronic documents that exist (sometimes) also in printed form, one distinction I have seen used quite a lot is *hard copy* and *soft copy* for the paper version and the electronic version, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

I would say "hard copies". #oldschoolers

Comment: Not all paper document are copies.

Comment: No, but isn't 'hard copies' the plural of 'hard copy', where 'copy' means matter/material/text?

Answer (score 6):

**Paper documents**

An online search for [security procedures "paper documents"] returns numerous examples of professional use of this phrase.

**Physical documents.**

Same, with this replacement.

Comment: +1 this avoids the problem of documents which consist of both hand-written notes and printed material

Answer (score -1):

try **electronic documents** and **paper documents**

"file" has potentially confusing connotations, and may sometimes be too restricted a term; if you want to be as general as possible avoid it. For the same reason I would avoid 'digital' too; it may also be too restrictive. I think 'paper' is okay, though; what documents are not usually paper? (Well, [tintypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tintype) and [ambrotypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrotype). Wait, is a video cassette a document? Yikes!)

Answer (score -3):

I suggest the words "hand drafted"

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation why this is a good choice.