# What is the origin of "analogue" as a term meaning "non-digital?"

Tags: etymology

This question came up when having a pun-ridden discussion with some of my colleagues: When and why did we start using the word "analogue" to mean "not using numerical digits?"

Etymonline only has an origin for the sense of "having analogy to something else," but that's not the meaning I'm interested in. It does mention that the "computing sense" is recorded from 1946, but not what the origin of that sense is.

I can guess there may once have been a specific and well-known analogy to which this use of the word was a reference, and that that analogy has since faded from common knowledge... But an uneducated guess is just folk etymology that hasn't yet spread. As this use of the word is apparently fairly young, I'm hoping there's a more reliably accurate origin story than mine out there.

Comment: Since computers were not something that most individuals had contact with before the 1980's, I'd surmise that "analogue" vs. "digital" came about to differentiate types of clocks and watches - which were widely available decades earlier. (Nope, I can't prove it.)

Comment: @Oldbag - The term "analog", to refer to non-computer electronics, was not used until about 1980.

Comment: @HotLicks - Really? Says who?

Comment: @Oldbag - Sez me.  The need only arose when consumer digital electronics began to appear.  As Maynard Wright indicates, the prior terms were "discrete" and "continuous".

Comment: @HotLicks - The devices that I'm referring to were mechanical - not electronic - I didn't notice that the question was limited to computer technology.

Comment: @Oldbag - The question is not limited to computers.  But it asks about the *origin* of the term "analog", and the term was originally applied to computers and not used for consumer electronics until about 1980.

Comment: **Astounding Stories** science fiction magazine (1930) morphed into **Analog Science Fact & Fiction** in **1960**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_Science_Fiction_and_Fact

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - But "analog", as used in that context, appeared to have nothing to do with computers or electronics.

Comment: Just to be clear
Digital was used from the onset of Morse code, this was then introduced, by the use of electromechanical relays, for signalling on train systems, circa late 1800s. records indicate the use of digital signals before this but it is a bit sketchy. You could argue that smoke signals where/are digital, how long have they been used...?

Comment: @Hotlicks, as an electrical engineer, my two cents is that "discrete" and "continuous" were not prior terms - they have a different meaning than (and are used in conjunction with) analog and digital.  That is, for example, you can have a continuous analog signal or a discrete analog signal - they mean different things.

Comment: @Brian -- As an electrical engineer, I disagree.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Analogue** comes from computing.

"A Chronology of Analogue Computing" article in [The Rutherford Journal](http://www.rutherfordjournal.org/article020106.html)

> The word ‘analogue’ **was first used as a technical term during the
> 1940s**, and referred specifically to a class of computing technology.
> Today, the word enjoys much wider usage, typically conveying
> continuity. For example, engineers will discuss analogue and digital
> signals, and musicians decide whether to record their work on analogue
> (continuous) or digital (discrete) media.
>
> **Analogue computing emerged during the nineteenth century** and became a
> mainstream computing technology during the early twentieth.

The word analogue has been used because the electric signal, for example, in analogue telephone line, is transmitted in a way that the voice vibrations correspond to electric signal fluctuation. In other word, the electric signal 'imitates' the voice.

In digital transmission, voice is coded into bytes, then is decoded with special protocol.

Another example is radio vs Morse code. Radio directly (by analogy) transmits the voice with electric signal variation. Morse code transmits only combinations of dots and dashes that are decoded by a trained person. So we can call Morse message digital because the concept is the same coding and decoding rather than an electric analogy of physical phenomena.

So the word analogue is used to reflect the concept when some physical phenomenon is converted into its electric signal analogue.

The word digital is used when a phenomenon properties are coded, then decoded.

Here are a few examples and articles to explain the difference between analogue and digital concept:

> The basic difference between analog and digital technology on [howstuffworks.com](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/question7.htm)
>
> Analog vs. Digital with explanation and comparison chart on [diffen.com](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Analog_vs_Digital)

Comment: Interesting information, but does it tell us (with supporting references) about 'the [historical] origin of “analogue” as a term meaning “non-digital”' rather than just the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, a good point, I expanded my answer with an article on the origins of the term. According to this article, the terms was first introduced in computing, then was borrowed by communications engineers and musicians.

Comment: I wish the kids I used to teach had had your attitude. Sorry I can only give you one merit star.

Comment: It doesn't have to be converted into an electric impulse analogue - it can be some other form that is analogous to the thing being represented. For instance the angle between a clock hand and the 12 mark is analogous to the time.

Comment: @bdsl that is right, a thermometer is also called an analog device if it has scaled tube, not display, but the principle is analogy in some form, either electric voltage or hands position or thermal expansion.

Comment: Given this origin, I'd have expected 'analogue' to become a synonym of digital, rather than taking on the opposed meaning it now has. Then again, it wouldn't be the first time English has done something that doesn't make sense even when explained.

Comment: @user867 , analogue can not be a synonym of digital because the principle is different. A good example is punched tape that was used in old computers to transmit data to processor versus magnetic tape in tape recorders used to play back sound. Punched tape stored 0 and 1 combinations while the tape stored magnetic signal of variable intensity. Also, it is not only English that adopted this terminology, other language use similar differentiation.

Comment: @javaNoobs Ah, I now see that I misread this answer as saying that this use of "analogue" arose because digital signals were an analogue of analogue signals. (You can see why I found this confusing.) Re-reading it now, I see what was actually intended, and it makes much more sense.

Comment: The interesting thing is that translating a signal into a number _is_ a form of analogy. But it's a different kind of analogy from mapping one physical quantity directly into some other physical quantity.

Comment: @Barmar, maybe you can call 'digital' 'indirect analogue'. Direct analogue devices are much dependent on the quality of signal transmittance whereas digital are only dependent on passing or not passing signals. Another interesting thing is that 'digital' technology usage is possible without electricity, like Morse code. Morse code can be transmitted with human gesture and flags from ship to shore or another ship but it uses 'digital' principle of coding and encoding signal - a combinations of dots and dashes.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the usage of the word comes from [analogue electronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogue_electronics).

> Analogue electronics (or analog in American English) are electronic systems with a continuously variable signal, in contrast to digital electronics where signals usually take only two levels. The term "analogue" describes the proportional relationship between a signal and a voltage or current that represents the signal. The word analogue is derived from the Greek word ανάλογος (analogos) meaning "proportional". (Wikipedia)

Comment: Great answer. Worth quoting the initial paragraph of that WP article.

Comment: Except that "analog electronics" is something of a back-formation.  At one time all electronic were analog.  The term was adopted from computing.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think so. As noted in the WP arcicle, the term was used for proportional relationships in electronic circuits.

Comment: @HonzaHaering - I know so.  The term "analog" was not applied to non-computer devices until about 1980.

Comment: @HotLicks See [here](http://goo.gl/vt0DUT) for the literature references from 1940s and 1950s using the term analog computing.

Comment: @HonzaHaering - As I said, "analog" was first applied to computers, and only applied to consumer electronics ca 1980, when the need to differentiate from digital consumer electronics arose.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't understand, why you're talking about consumer electronics, but anyway, I think we got the point.

Comment: The point is that saying the term derives from "analog electronics" is a circular argument, since we're talking about the term "analog" in ordinary ("consumer") electronics.  The term came from "analog computer".

Comment: @HotLicks This is not true. My uncle was an army electrical engineer who worked on America's early computers. He taught me the term in the 1960's and indicated that he had been using it since at least the 50's, and he was very explicit in it's use for non-computing devices well before the 1980's,. (specifically in communications and signaling electronics in the 50's, which is were he got his start)  And the explanation that he gave was essentially identical to the one above.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - It is, in part, a question of whether we're discussing the use of the term as technical jargon vs it's use as an "everyday" term.  I and my compatriots would occasionally use "analog" to differentiate from "digital" for non-computer components back in the 70s (when I was doing hardware design), but we kind of winked when we did it.  And it was clearly drawing on the analogy to digital and analog computers.  Prior to the advent of (non-computer) digital electronics there was no need for the term, outside of computing.

Comment: @HotLicks  You may have winked, but my uncle did not.  And just to be clear, Teletypes and their competitors (which preceded computers) used *digital* signaling and was called such by engineers since at least the late 1950's.  And though they could also be used with computers, they were *communications* devices, not computers. So, yes, there were both non-computer digital electronics before the 1980's and use of the comparison "*analog vs digital*" wrt to them.  If you want to walk the claim back to "popular terminology", that's a different story.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Well, back when I was working with TTYs, from 1969 through 1974 (with a brief refresher ca 1979), I don't recall them being referred to a "digital".  (They were, in fact, just a glorified telegraph.)  But admittedly that was a long time ago.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Check out the [ASR 33 manual](http://www.soemtron.org/downloads/teletypes/asr33teletypemanualtelet11.pdf).  There's unfortunately no scan available on that PDF, but I looked through it for several minutes and I could not find the word "digital" anywhere.

Comment: @Honza Haering.  Good answe, the only correct one.  I will vote for it if you (a) clarify that the term was established and used decades before the digital era; that it still has the same meaning; that it means "non-digital" only to uneducated folk; and thus the Question of when it came into use as "non-digital" is irrelevant because it doesn't mean that, I will vote for it. IOT, clear up the confusion introduced by both the seeker and HotLicks.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - What about multi-level logic?  There are digital schemes where a single wire can have 4 or more levels.

Comment: @Honza Haering. (b) change *signals usually take only two levels* to *the signal is not continuous, it is either on or off, and when it is on, it has a single non-varying value*. (c) mention that it has NO relation to *analogy*.

Comment: @Hot Licks. Logic does not apply here. Logic may have many channels or "levels", but each line of "logic" is implemented as a circuit.  The actual meaning has to do with a single circuit, and the type of signal on it.  If the signal (electrical charge) is continuous (ie. it always has a charge, and the charge varies), it is an analogue circuit; otherwise it isn't.

Comment: @Hot Licks. Even the term *digital* is confused in the colloquial usage, it means something specific in technology, but it is colloquially taken to mean digits, as in an analogue clock face vs a digital one (per the Question) ... they are both still clocks ... and there it has nothing to do with the signal: a spring-driven clock has no electrical signal that varies.  So the colloquial usage *analogue* is wrong, but easily understood.

Comment: But the fact remains that the *origin* of "analog" to mean "not digital" (ie, actually answering the OP's question) comes from the terminology used to distinguish between analog and digital computers.  The use with computers predates other uses of that distinction by 20 years or so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23180/discussion-between-performancedba-and-hot-licks).

Answer (score 3):

The original electronic computers were "analog".  The computations were done by adding/subtracting/integrating/differentiating electronic signals (voltages), so these signals were "analogs" of the real-life values being modeled.

(There were also various types of electromechanical computers, of course, from Babbage's "Difference Engine" to Turing's code-breaking device to several others in England and the US. The devices were incredibly slow and unreliable, though -- and noisy!)

"Digital" electronic computers (generally considered to start with the Eniac at University of Pennsylvania) were so-named to differentiate from analog ones.

Comment: I agree.  In the late 1960s I operated a Qeleq analog computer, which was hard-wired for one job: Least-Cost Animal Feed Formulation.  It contained an array of modules, one per potential feed ingredient, each itself consisting of an array of tuneable potentiometers, each representing one parameter of the ingredient  -  % protein, % fibre, etc.  The point of 'analog' was that resistance of each 'pot' was analogous to a real-world quantity.

Comment: This answer is incorrect for many reasons.  The term existed and was used (ie. it had specific technical meaning and context) decades before the digital era. Analogue means *Difference*, the change in the electrical charge, hence *Difference Engine* clearly described the fact that it was based on the change in the charge.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - The Difference Engine was no more "analog" than a [Marchant calculator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchant_calculator).  And *analog* does not mean *difference*, is means "something that is similar in some ways to something else".

Comment: @HotLicks, agreed. 'Difference' in early computing was about generating mathematical tables.

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MxYkAAAAMAAJ&lpg=RA4-PA24&dq=%22analog%22&pg=RA4-PA24#v=onepage&q=%22analog%22&f=false) is a reference (from 1949) that supports your claim: "digital computers count numbers as the Chinese count on an abacus, while an analog computer makes believe it is itself the physical process to be studied". I could not find any reference to "analog signals", etc., until the 60s.

Comment: [Another reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SJQEAQAAIAAJ&q=%22analog+quantity%22&dq=%22analog+quantity%22) from 1950 that also uses *analog* in the sense of *continuous* ("analog quantity"), although the primary meaning is very clearly still that of a physical analogy.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier radio and electronics references often classified signals and/or variables as "continuous" or "discrete" as on page 981 of the Fourth Edition (1956) of "Reference Data for Radio Engineers," published by ITT.

Answer (score 1):

When the word analogue became an antonym of digital is a question that might better be reversed, since "analogue" certainly preceded "digital" as a description of means of representation. The continuous or discrete description for analogue and digital respectively is perhaps the most universal explanation of the difference in representation of data. The first instance is empiric (based on experience), the second abstractive (based on theory). This is illustrated by the fact that in an analogue recording the data stream follows a direct perception or stimulus, whereas a digital recording generates bytes based on probability. The first simply expresses a more direct causal connection to the origin of the data than the second.

Comment: OK, so what's the answer to my question? I already know what the words mean; I want to know how they came to have those meanings.

Comment: @user867 - This answers the question, only the answer is that your question is improperly framed.  Analog came first, and when digital came along it had to differentiate itself from analog (by using "digital" instead of "analog").

Comment: @HotLicks I am aware that both of these words took on new meanings at around the same time, one in response to the other. I wish to know when and why this event occurred, and this you have not explained. Like the tennis player in the old hot air balloon joke, your answer is both technically correct and not actually useful.

Comment: @user867 - Oleksandr R has elsewhere in this thread posted comments showing a reference to analog and digital computers in 1949, with precisely the same meanings as today.  That goes back to the dawn of digital computing (though analog computing goes back farther).

Comment: @HotLicks If that information is an important part of the answer, it should be made a part of the answer; The SE format requires that a good answer stand alone. (Oh, but include references where attribution is appropriate.) Also, if the only part of the answer that answers the question is contained entirely within another answer, then shouldn't this answer be an upvote and a comment on that answer?

Comment: @user867 - The point is that your question, as stated, is ill-formed.  And you have repeatedly refused to acknowledge this.

Comment: @HotLicks I... guess I don't really understand why it being ill-formed is so important? I mean, I'm willing to accept that the use of "analogue" to mean "not digital" arose because "digital" started being used to mean "not analogue." But I already knew that the origins of these two words' new meanings were tied, and saying that the egg came before the chicken, rather than the other way around, doesn't explain anything useful about the circumstances in which these new meanings arose. So, I guess I must be missing something; What am I overlooking?

Comment: @user867 - Then what is your question???

Comment: @HotLicks From the original question: **"When and why did we start using the word 'analogue' to mean 'not using numerical digits?'"** I'm not really sure how I can make it clearer. Maybe if I restate it in different words... **At some point in the past, it was important and common to disambiguate whether information was stored or transmitted in an encoded form or a non-encoded one; I want to know what that circumstance was, when it occurred, and why the term "analogue" in particular was used when there were doubtlessly other words that could have been used.** Preferably with references.

Comment: This answer currently describes the new meanings the two words took on, but doesn't describe the circumstances which led to those new meanings were adopted, when that circumstance arose, nor why the particular word I asked about was used.

Comment: @user867 - We never started using "analog(ue)" to mean "not using numerical digits".  An "analog" watch uses numerical digits.

Comment: @HotLicks The word "analogue" *is* used to mean "not using numerical digits" in several contexts other than watches, such as when describing radio waves where continuous modulation of the wave carries part or all of the signal. It's how old-time radio and TV broadcasts used to work before digital broadcasting took over, as well as how most phone networks still function. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_transmission .) We must have started using it this way at some point, and that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: @user867 - As has been stated many times, "analog(ue)" (as in "analog computer) goes back many decades -- to the 30s, if not earlier.   "Digital" (as in "digital computer") goes back to the dawn of digital computers, which would be the 40s.  But until the mid 70s or so the distinction was only known to computer nerds -- it wasn't until 1975-1980 that digital technology penetrated the consumer market to the extent that consumers needed a distinguishing terminology.

Comment: @user867 - Oleksandr R provided [this link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MxYkAAAAMAAJ&lpg=RA4-PA24&dq=%22analog%22&pg=RA4-PA24#v=onepage&q=%22analog%22&f=false) from 1949, which shows the two terms defined as they still are today.  This may be the earliest documented mention of the two together, and is probably the best you can do in terms of establishing a date.

Comment: @HotLicks If that information is relevant to this answer, it should be edited into the answer, rather than left in the comments section.

Comment: @user867 - So, write your own answer.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm satisfied with the one I've already accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly from Ancient Greek prefix ἀνα- (ana-), from ἀνά (aná, “on, up, above, throughout”) and logos, loosely defined as a word (as embodying an idea), a statement, a speech...

Cf. "logic"... which opens up a whole 'nother can of worms... :)

- http://biblehub.com/greek/3056.htm
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_in_computer_science